# How to get list of exist areas ui_type?

Tags: python

If type `bpy.context.area.ui_type = ''` in console, this will throw an error and offer an enumeration of the existing types, like: `"... not found in ('VIEW_3D', 'IMAGE_EDITOR', 'UV', 'CompositorNodeTree', 'TIMELINE', etc.)"`

How to get this list of `ui_types` of `areas`?

Comment: I think you are looking for [this](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/space_type_items.html#rna-enum-space-type-items)

Comment: AFAIK the only way to get this using python is to force the error by setting it to a wrong value, catch the exception as a string, parse the values between the parentheses and separate them. Or you can use the docs as Ratt mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @[Gorgious](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/86891/gorgious) has mentioned you can catch the exception and then parse out the values like this:

```
import bpy
import re

try:
    bpy.context.area.ui_type = ''
except TypeError as e:
    match = re.search(r'not found in \((.*)\)', str(e))
    if match:
        enums = match.group(1).split(', ')
        enums = [enum.strip("'") for enum in enums]
    else:
        raise e

print()
print(enums)
```

Comment: What's the difference between `except TypeError as e:` and `except Exception as e:`?

Comment: `Exception` is the base class of `TypeError` where TypeError is the subclass or derived class. Some call this relationship a parent class and child class. It 
inherits from Exception class https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp