# How to print out all Shared Enum items via Python API

Tags: python, scripting

This is the all Shared Enums that I want to print out their names and identifiers of every enum_items:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/index.html

```
import bpy

def get_all_shared_enum():
    ...
    return [...]

for rna in get_all_shared_enum():
    print(rna)
    for item in rna.enum_items:
        print(item.name, item.identifier)
    print()
```

If not, how to print out one Shared Enum like Window Cursor Items: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/window_cursor_items.html

Comment: Unfortunately it seems it's not directly accessible to the API. The only way I know of is to set the enum prop to a known wrong value, catch the exception and parse the valid values. You read that right :) https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/284383/86891