How to Get All Possible Values of an EnumProperty in Blender Python
I'm developing a script where I need to retrieve the available values of some EnumProperties in Blender. I found a similar question already answered here. However, for some reason, this approach does not work with the property bpy.context.scene.render.engine.
Here is the code I am using, based on the provided answer by @ideasman42:
import bpy

def enum_members_from_type(rna_type, prop_str):
    prop = rna_type.bl_rna.properties[prop_str]
    return [e.identifier for e in prop.enum_items]

def enum_members_from_instance(rna_item, prop_str):
    return enum_members_from_type(type(rna_item), prop_str)

# Test the functions above:
enum = enum_members_from_instance(bpy.context.scene.render, "engine")
print(enum)

The problem is that it returns only this value:
['BLENDER_EEVEE']

I am expecting to get all possible render engine values like CYCLES, BLENDER_EEVEE, etc. Could anyone help me understand why this is happening and how I can retrieve all possible values for bpy.context.scene.render.engine?
Thank you!
Additional Information:

Blender Version: 4.1.0 (also tried 3.5)
OS: Windows 11


This can help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/284383/how-to-get-list-of-exist-areas-ui-type

The script you provided does not work for builtin enums unfortunately. You can use either of the suggested answers. I don't know of any other way apart from hardcoding it
